# Will Google Scholar index the papers on my website?

Tags: search-engine-indexing

I have just requested that Google Scholar collect the papers from my personal web site: http://cs.uic.edu/~asmirnov/publications.html

I was wondering if I did everything right:

1. I submitted a request on the form provided on scholar web site
2. I published the papers in PDF on my web site
3. Is there anything else needed for Google to index my web site?

Other questions are:

1. The first paper (that is linked) is not to just a paper, but a whole issue.
2. Are there any tags to be added on my web site?  If so, which, and how do I add them?
3. What are the exporting options available on Google scholar web site and how do they work?

Answer (score 1):

This question is now old, and there are no longer any PDFs linked on http://cs.uic.edu/~asmirnov/publications.html, so I'll skip the first set of questions. It is no longer possible to review your setup.

But I'll answer your three "other questions":

1. Every PDF handed to Google Scholar must be a *single* paper. Submitting a whole issue as a single PDF-file is not accepted. Quoting from  the Google Scholar [Inclusion Guidelines for Webmasters](http://scholar.google.no/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html#indexing):

   > "Place each article and each abstract in a separate HTML or PDF file. At this time, we're unable to effectively index multiple abstracts on the same webpage or multiple papers in the same PDF file. Likewise, we're unable to index different sections of the same paper in different files. Each paper must have its own unique URL in order for it to be included in Google Scholar."
2. Google Scholar will scrape your PDF for meta-data.  So just linking to a full text PDF of a single paper will work if its format follow certain "conventions".  See the section "Indexing of content without the meta-tags" in the Google Scholar [Inclusion Guidelines for Webmasters](http://scholar.google.no/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html#indexing) for details about these "conventions".

   However, for better control over the meta-data, it is recommended that you supply a *HTML abstract* with meta-tags along with the full text PDF. For a link to the Google Scholar guidelines for this file, see the section "Configuring the meta-tags " in the same document.
3. Google Scholar prefer sites to export meta-data through *HTML abstract* files with meta-data embedded as meta-tags.  What tags to use and how to embed them are described in the Google Scholar [Inclusion Guidelines for Webmasters](http://scholar.google.no/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html#indexing).